# ace editor find code snippet

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

i have setup ace to render html code let's say for example that he renderer the following code

```
    1 <html>
    2 <body>
    3 <table>
    4 <tr>
    5 <td>
    6 test
    7 </td>
```

I would like to get the line number for a given fragment of my code, so for example if i search

```
"<html><body><table><tr><td>"
```

i would like to move the cursor and higlight line 6.
Unfortunately ace built in find function only seems to find code that are at the same line so

```
ace.find('<html>', options)
```

work and highlight line 1 but

```
ace.find('<html><body>', options)
```

doesn't find anything at all.

Could you explain me why or give me a workaround ?
Thanks by advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `<html>` and `<body>` are on different lines you need to search for `ace.find('<html>\n<body>', options)` (with `\n`)

another way is to use regexp to find offset you want in the `editor.getValue()` string, and use

```
pos = session.doc.indexToPosition(100)
session.selection.moveToPosition(pos)
```

to move cursor to it

Comment: my problem is that i don't know if it's on 2 different lines, i just know that i want to search for (<html><body>') moreover `ace.find('<html>\n<body>', options) doesn't work either

Comment: if you want to search for `<html><body>` but also allow other characters between them, then you are not searching for `<html><body>`, but for something different. E.g. regexp `<html>\s*<body>` or maybe you are searching for `<html[^>]+>\s*<body[^>]+>`. Anyway you need to decide what you are searching for, to have a chance to find it.

Comment: I understand what you say, maybe i misguided you saying that i want to search the sentence `<html><body>` in fact i allready know that the code inside the editor contain and start with this two tags(the code inside the editor came froma a  sentence like `<html><body>...`), i just want to find a way to select it and highlight the line that his after body

Comment: Then yo can search only for `<body>` and set cursor after it, right?

Comment: In fact i have to implement a kind of reverse wysiwyg editor where when you click on an html element the corresponding line highlight in ace so, for body you're right but, for example if the user click on a tr on table, it became more complicated (the html can have many table, many row, ...) so i made a function that give me a string containing all the html code that is before the html element that the user clicked, and i REALLY  want to select all the code beginning at position 0 and containing all the tag inside my ''htmlstring''

Comment: now that you mention it maybe there's a length settings that might help me.

Comment: anyway thanks for you're help ;), i will update this thread when i have found a suitable solution

Comment: if you have offset in the string and want to move cursor to it, use `indexToPosition` (see updated answer)

Comment: thank you for you're answer, editor.getSession().doc.$lines, really helped me solved my problem and combined with session.selection.moveToPosition(pos), you've gave me a perfectly workable solution thank ;)